# PHP Converting array to nested array based on a similar value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have PHP array as mentioned below

```
$arr=array(array("Employee ID0","Employee Name0","Leave Date1"),
    array("Employee ID1","Employee Name1","Leave Date0"),
    array("Employee ID2","Employee Name2","Leave Date0"),
    array("Employee ID3","Employee Name3","Leave Date1"));
```

now i want to group by leave date like mentioned below

```
$arr=array("Leave Date0"=>array(("Employee ID1","Employee Name1"),
     ("Employee ID2","Employee Name2")),
     "Leave Date1"=>array(("Employee ID0","Employee Name0"),
     ("Employee ID3","Employee Name3"))
)
```

unable to come up with any logic for this, if anyone can help it will be great.

Comment: How do you want us to know the difference between employee name and employee name? Make an example worth the bytes it uses.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = [
    ["Employee ID0", "Employee Name0", "Leave Date1"],
    ["Employee ID1", "Employee Name1", "Leave Date0"],
    ["Employee ID2", "Employee Name2", "Leave Date0"],
    ["Employee ID3", "Employee Name3", "Leave Date1"]
];

$output = [];
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $output[$value[2]][] = [$value[0], $value[1]];
}

var_export($output);
```

Pretty sure this should give you what you are looking for.

NOTE: If you don't mind having the "Leave DateX" section duplicated in the output values, you can replace `[$value[0], $value[1]]` with `$value` for a slightly cleaner look.